table with images
I need to make a table with images, 9 rows and 4 columns. The first column will contain text, and the remaining 3 columns will contain the images. The following screenshot shows the desired layout.
Depending on the image sizes, the table may need to span more than 1 page.
Added piece of information: It’s important that the third image column be (about) 50% wider than the first two.


How should we know if any approach we would suggest is easier than whatever solutions you already found?

Welcome // "I found a few ways but i'm looking for much simpler" sounds like the song "50 ways to leave your lover". Code tells us more. Please add. For the images I suggest to follow sam's link and use the provided example-images.

Or just tell us the size of the images so we can substitute.

`\begin{longtblr}{
colspec={Q[valign=b]Q[valign=h]Q[valign=h]Q[valign=h]},
row{1}={halign=c},
vlines,
hlines
}
sda & Front & Back & Side \
AAAA   &
\adjustbox{width=4cm,keepaspectratio}{\includegraphics{example-grid-100x100pt}} &
\adjustbox{width=4cm,keepaspectratio}{\includegraphics{example-grid-100x100pt}} &
\adjustbox{width=5cm,keepaspectratio}{\includegraphics{example-image-duck}} \
\end{longtblr}`

sorry for not specifying what i've already tried. It doesn't matter caz ur way is way better

but I dont know how to alined images because the last one not 1:1 ratio

Would you say that the third column should be 50% wider than the other two columns?

I think 50% wider  would  be perfect

This question is similar to: Centering Images and text inside a table. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@cabohah - The present query is not a duplicate: An important, non-redundant part its formatting objective is to automate the process of having one data column be 50% wider than the other two data columns.

Here's a solution that employs the xltabular package and eponymous environment. Basically, xltabular combines the capabilities of longtable (allow page breaks in the table) and tabularx (set a target for the table's overall width; determine widths of X-type columns as residuals). Note that, per your comment, I've set the usable width of the third data column to be 50% larger than that of the other two.
Be sure to load the graphicx package without the demo option in your real document.

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
%\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document

\usepackage{xltabular} % for 'xltabular' env. 
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}} % vertical centering
  % Define a variable-width X-type column, cell contents centered horizontally:
\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X} 
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules

\begin{document}

\begingroup % limit the scope of the next two instructions
\renewcommand\tabcolsep{4pt} % default: 6pt
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\hsize,height=\hsize,keepaspectratio}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} c Y{0.8571} Y{0.8571} Y{1.2858} @{}} 
   % 6/7+6/7+9/7 = 21/7 = 3; 9/7 = 1.5*6/7; 0.8571=6/7; 1.2858=9/7.

%% headers and footers

\toprule
Sample & Front view & Back view & Cross-sectional view \\
\midrule
\endhead

\bottomrule
\endfoot

%% body of table

A & 
\includegraphics{a} &
\includegraphics{b} &
\includegraphics[height=0.6667\hsize]{c} \\
\addlinespace
N & 
\includegraphics{d} &
\includegraphics{e} &
\includegraphics[height=0.6667\hsize]{f} \\
\addlinespace
C & 
\includegraphics{g} &
\includegraphics{h} &
\includegraphics[height=0.6667\hsize]{i} \\
\addlinespace
ANAN & 
\includegraphics{j} &
\includegraphics{k} &
\includegraphics[height=0.6667\hsize]{l} \\
\addlinespace
NANA & 
\includegraphics{m} &
\includegraphics{n} &
\includegraphics[height=0.6667\hsize]{o} \\

\end{xltabular}
\endgroup

\end{document}

